# XPath - How to extract element following by the parent parent H1 tag

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to extract blog post from web pages. Different pages have different structure so it is very difficult to extract what I need. There are some **CSS** and **JS** code in the **HTML** section also, I have to avoid them.

- I know `<h1> a dummy title </h1>` from previous, so it can help to validate the exact one.
- I do not know any ID and CLASS attribute.

```
<body>
      <div>
         <h1> a dummy title </h1>
      </div>

            <script> function loadDoc() {const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();} </script>

        <div class="subtitle">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-post">
            <p>...</p>
                <div class="clear-fix">...</div>
            <p>...</p>
                <div class="clear-fix">...</div>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
       </div>

       <div class="another-section">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
       </div>

       <div class="another-another-section">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
                <div class="clear-fix">...</div>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
       </div>
</body>
```

**What I have tried with:** 
I have tried to find the `<div>` with maximum `<p>` but sometimes there are some other `<div>` with maximum `<p>`, I have to avoid them by finding nearest `<h1>`

```
$html= 
'[My html above]

';
$HTMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$HTMLDoc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );   
$xpath = new DOMXPath($HTMLDoc);

#locate the 3 divs
$pees = $xpath->query('//div[.//p]');
$pchilds = [];

#get the number of p children in each div
foreach ($pees as $pee) {
    $childs = $pee->childElementCount;
    array_push($pchilds,$childs);}

#now find the div with the max number of p children
foreach ($pees as $pee) {
    $childs = $pee->childElementCount;
    if ($childs == max($pchilds))
       echo ($pee->nodeValue);
       #or do whatever
}
```

Comment: You say: "I have tried to find the <div> with maximum <p> but sometimes there are some other <div> with maximum <p>, I have to avoid them by finding nearest <h1>"

Could you make that clear in your example. Which you `do` want to find and which you `don't` want to find.

Comment: @Siebe Jongebloed, I really want to find the first <h1> then I want to find the most nearest <div> having max <p>. There can be another tags in that <div> but I want to print <p> tags only.

Answer (score 1):

Find all divs with `p` elements, then counting `p` elements inside each, finally getting the first with the `max()` count

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$dcnt = array();
// Find all divs following an H1
$divs = $xpath->query('//h1/following-sibling::div');

// Count `p` inside them
foreach($divs as $idx=>$d) {
    $cnt = (int) $xpath->evaluate('count(.//p)', $d);
    $dcnt[$idx] = $cnt;
}

// show content of div with max() count
foreach($divs as $idx=>$d) {
   if( $dcnt[$idx] == max($dcnt) ){
        print $idx . ': ' . $divs[$idx]->nodeName . ': ' . $divs[$idx]->nodeValue;
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: 2 issues are remaining. 1->`div` inside `max div` are also printing. 2-> If `<h1>` is out of the parent `div`, how to detect the `max div` ? e.g. If I delete the most outer div then the `<h1>` will independent or it can be in another `div`. In this cases, I want to detect the first `<h1>` then I want to find out the first nearest `<div>` with max `<p>` then I want to print only the p tags. Do you have another approaches ?

Comment: "div inside max div are also printing": use `$xpath->query('./p',$d)` inside second loop to get p only. 2. it's hard to say without a html sample.

Comment: I have edited html sample with followings

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 solution (see [SaxonC](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) for PHP support). Find the first first nearest div after `<h1>` containing with max `<p>` :

```
//h1/following-sibling::div[p[max(//h1/following-sibling::div/count(p))]][1]
```

Output :

```
<div class="blog-post">
            <p>...</p>
                <div class="clear-fix">...</div>
            <p>...</p>
                <div class="clear-fix">...</div>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
       </div>'
```

XPath 1.0 approximate solution (could return the wrong div) :

```
//h1/following-sibling::div[count(./p)>1][count(./p)>count(./preceding-sibling::div[./p][1]/p)][count(./p)>count(./following-sibling::div[./p][1]/p)][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you added,

> want to find the first <h1> then I want to find the most nearest 
> <div> having max <p>.
> There can be another tags in that <div> but I want to print 
> <p> tags only.

If your PHP processor has [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) [support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.hasexsltsupport.php)
something like this should be possible:

```sh
  < file xmlstarlet select --template \
  --var T='//div[p][contains(preceding::h1[1],"my title")]' \
  --copy-of '($T[count(p) = math:max(dyn:map($T,"count(p)"))])[1]/p'
```

where

- the `T` variable selects the `div` nodes of interest, assuming
  you know, or can extract, the `h1` section header text
- [`dyn:map`](https://exslt.github.io/dyn/functions/map/index.html)
  maps each `div` to the count of its `p` children,
  [`math:max`](https://exslt.github.io/math/functions/max/index.html)
  picks the maximum count
- `($T[…])[1]/p` selects the `p` children of the first of possibly
  more `div`s with a maximum `p` count

The command above uses [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) syntax; to make a single XPath
expression replace `$T` (2 places) with `T` contents inside parentheses.
It executes the following XSLT stylesheet (add `-C` before `--template`
to list it):

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="math dyn">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable select="//div[p][contains(preceding::h1[1],&quot;my title&quot;)]" name="T"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="($T[count(p) = math:max(dyn:map($T,&quot;count(p)&quot;))])[1]/p"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```