# How do I receive data Xml in php?

Tags: php, xml, api

file xml is in page info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response error="false" message="">
    <community-outlook>
            <symbols>
                    <symbol>
                    <name>EURUSD</name>
                    <shortPercentage>44</shortPercentage>
                    <longPercentage>56</longPercentage>
                    <shortVolume>6512.91</shortVolume>
                    <longVolume>8408.02</longVolume>
                    <longPositions>27060</longPositions>
                    <shortPositions>18173</shortPositions>
                    <totalPositions>45233</totalPositions>
                    <avgShortPrice>1.0673</avgShortPrice>
                    <avgLongPrice>1.0975</avgLongPrice>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol>
                    <name>GBPUSD</name>
                    <shortPercentage>32</shortPercentage>
                    <longPercentage>68</longPercentage>
                    <shortVolume>2940.66</shortVolume>
                    <longVolume>6183.52</longVolume>
                    <longPositions>20931</longPositions>
                    <shortPositions>9158</shortPositions>
                    <totalPositions>30089</totalPositions>
                    <avgShortPrice>1.2475</avgShortPrice>
                    <avgLongPrice>1.2930</avgLongPrice>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol>
                    <name>USDJPY</name>
                    <shortPercentage>79</shortPercentage>
                    <longPercentage>21</longPercentage>
                    <shortVolume>8078.40</shortVolume>
                    <longVolume>2161.13</longVolume>
                    <longPositions>3650</longPositions>
                    <shortPositions>20527</shortPositions>
                    <totalPositions>24177</totalPositions>
                    <avgShortPrice>123.2377</avgShortPrice>
                    <avgLongPrice>127.8273</avgLongPrice>
                    </symbol>
            </symbols>
            <general>
                    <demoAccountsPercentage>34</demoAccountsPercentage>
                    <realAccountsPercentage>65</realAccountsPercentage>
                    <profitablePercentage>64</profitablePercentage>
                    <nonProfitablePercentage>35</nonProfitablePercentage>
                    <fundsWon>1,860,381,563.81</fundsWon>
                    <fundsLost>-1,732,264,647.37</fundsLost>
                    <averageDeposit>62,892.16</averageDeposit>
                    <averageAccountProfit>70,785.39</averageAccountProfit>
                    <averageAccountLoss>-65,910.69</averageAccountLoss>
                    <totalFunds>1,652,931,672.97</totalFunds>
            </general>
    </community-outlook>
</response>
```

php new1.PHP is:

```
<?php
$checknamedatahitbtcA = file_get_contents("info.xml");
$ragabchecknamehitbtcA = json_decode($checknamedatahitbtcA, true);
foreach($ragabchecknamehitbtcA as $itemA)
{
foreach($itemA as $itemB)
{
echo $itemB;// this is info like name & shortPercentage & longPercentage & shortVolume
echo '<br>';
}
}
?>
```

I can't view this info
name
shortPercentage
longPercentage
shortVolume
longVolume
longPositions
shortPositions
totalPositions
avgShortPrice
avgLongPrice

there this erro
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\forex\new1.PHP on line 4

Comment: Parse it [as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72418497/2834978) , not json.

Comment: As per @LMC (+1), you use code like `json_decode()` but you already understand that it is XML format, and not JSON. So, why do you do this and expect error-free?